# Python.'NoneType' object has no attribute 'b'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am getting an error when i want to get coupon code using beautifulsoap

This is a part of page:

```html
 <ul class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-links"><div class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-divider"></div>
<li><a href="/pk/c/womens_sale_events/35OffWearNowStyles?intcmp=seealloffersnav_1_spanstylefontweight500top035offourfavoritewearnowstylesonlineonlyusecodebstylefontweight700top0hisummerbspan"><div><span style="font-weight: 500; top: 0">35% off our favorite wear-now styles.* Online only. Use code <b style="font-weight: 700; top: 0">HISUMMER.</b></span></div></a><button type="button" class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-details-button" aria-describedby="dialogDetailsBtn-0">Details</button></li>
<li><a href="/pk/c/womens_sale_events/35OffWearNowStyles?intcmp=seealloffersnav_1_spanstylefontweight500top035offourfavoritewearnowstylesonlineonlyusecodebstylefontweight700top0hisummerbspan"><div><span style="font-weight: 500; top: 0">35% off our favorite wear-now styles.* Online only. Use code <b style="font-weight: 700; top: 0">MAY20.</b></span></div></a><button type="button" class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-details-button" aria-describedby="dialogDetailsBtn-0">Details</button></li>
</ul>
```

This is my Code:

```
def parse(self, response):

    self.mongo.GetAllDocuments()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    url,off,coupon,itemtype = "","","",""
    containersC=soup.select(".nc-nav__promo-modal--global-links > li")
    for itemC in containersC:
        coupon = itemC.a.div.span.b.text
```

I am getting the following error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'b'`

Comment: You should check that `itemC.a.div.span` is not `None` before proceeding. In fact, that probably applies to all parent elements `itemC`, `itemC.a` and `itemC.a.div` separately as well.

Comment: it goes fine upto itemC.a.div but i want to get b tag which is inside div then span

Comment: Obviously, there are parts of your HTML pages used where there is no span element inside the div (inside the a, inside the ... etc). You need to account for those possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is assuming that the structure of the HTML is the same for all instances. If the `b` (or any other element) is missing, you will get that error. One approach would be to first test for the presence of a `b` tag before attempting to print it, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """ <ul class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-links"><div class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-divider"></div>
<li><a href="/pk/c/womens_sale_events/35OffWearNowStyles?intcmp=seealloffersnav_1_spanstylefontweight500top035offourfavoritewearnowstylesonlineonlyusecodebstylefontweight700top0hisummerbspan"><div><span style="font-weight: 500; top: 0">35% off our favorite wear-now styles.* Online only. Use code <b style="font-weight: 700; top: 0">HISUMMER.</b></span></div></a><button type="button" class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-details-button" aria-describedby="dialogDetailsBtn-0">Details</button></li>
<li><a href="/pk/c/womens_sale_events/35OffWearNowStyles?intcmp=seealloffersnav_1_spanstylefontweight500top035offourfavoritewearnowstylesonlineonlyusecodebstylefontweight700top0hisummerbspan"><div><span style="font-weight: 500; top: 0">35% off our favorite wear-now styles.* Online only. Use code <b style="font-weight: 700; top: 0">MAY20.</b></span></div></a><button type="button" class="nc-nav__promo-modal--global-details-button" aria-describedby="dialogDetailsBtn-0">Details</button></li>
</ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for li_tag in soup.select(".nc-nav__promo-modal--global-links > li"):
    b_tag = li_tag.find('b')

    if b_tag:
        print(b_tag.text)
```

For your HTML, this gives:

```
HISUMMER.
MAY20.
```

Comment: That was missing one tag.